# Update query using Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum

I have 2 codes I'm having trouble with.  I looked at some of the other answers but got totally confused.  Here is the SQL code..  (Its an Access, SQL pass thru query)

```
UPDATE    TOP (500) InventorySuppliers
SET              BoydQuantityAvailable = SUM(Boyd0004Daily.QOH), Cost = Boyd0004Daily.Cost
FROM         Boyd0004Daily INNER JOIN
                      InventorySuppliers ON Boyd0004Daily.LocalSKU = InventorySuppliers.LocalSKU
WHERE     (InventorySuppliers.SupplierID = 4) AND (NOT (InventorySuppliers.BoydQuantityAvailable = SUM(Boyd0004Daily.QOH))) OR
                      (InventorySuppliers.SupplierID = 4) AND (NOT (InventorySuppliers.Cost = Boyd0004Daily.Cost))
```

It doesnt like the Update on the SUM(Boyd0004Daily.QOH) but for the life of me, I havent been able to figure out how to rewrite it so it does a select, then an update with 1 query.

Comment: what error are you getting? Is there a non-numeric value in `Boyd0004Daily.QOH` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is get the select to come out right:

```
select *
from InventorySuppliers i
inner join (select LocalSKU, SUM(QOH) QOH_SUM, MAX(Cost) Cost --max or min
            from Boyd0004Daily
            group by LocalSKU) a 
        on a.LocalSKU = i.LocalSKU
where i.SupplierID = 4
and ((i.BoydQuantityAvailable != a.QOH_SUM))
    OR i.Cost != a.Cost))
```

Then convert your select to an update:

```
update i
set i.BoydQuantityAvailable = a.QOH_SUM,
    i.Cost = a.Cost
from InventorySuppliers i
inner join (select LocalSKU, SUM(QOH) QOH_SUM, MAX(Cost) Cost --max or min
            from Boyd0004Daily
            group by LocalSKU) a 
        on a.LocalSKU = i.LocalSKU
where i.SupplierID = 4
    and ((i.BoydQuantityAvailable != a.QOH_SUM))
        OR i.Cost != a.Cost))
```

I think this query should work for you.  I may have errors since I can't test on your data.

Comment: I'll know shortly if it works, I had to modify it a little to remove an extra bracket.    update i
set i.BoydQuantityAvailable = a.QOH_SUM,
    i.Cost = a.Cost
from InventorySuppliers i
inner join (select LocalSKU, SUM(QOH) QOH_SUM, MAX(Cost) Cost --max or min
            from Boyd0004Daily
            group by LocalSKU) a 
        on a.LocalSKU = i.LocalSKU
where i.SupplierID = 4
    and ((i.BoydQuantityAvailable != a.QOH_SUM)
        OR i.Cost != a.Cost)

Comment: I wanted to thank you for all of your help.  Works fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `group by`. Any time you use an aggregate function, you must include a group by that includes all columns that are not being aggregated.

You are also using `SUM` in your `WHERE` clause which will not work.  When you want to filter results based on an aggregate you must use `HAVING` instead.

Comment: Yes I realise the problem is using the SUM in the WHERE clause, but for the life of me I cant figure out how to get around it..

Comment: As for the group by, I need to group by boyd0004Daily.LocalSKU